# Accessing a SerializerMethodField in create()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a password on server side and send it back to the user. Below is the code I have written:

```
class ASCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(write_only = True)
    password = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_password(self, obj):
        from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
        password = get_random_string(length=16)
        return password

    def create(self, validated_data):
        name = validated_data['name']
        as = AS.objects.get_or_create(name = name,
                    password = validated_data['password']
                )
```

I am getting a key error for 'password'. How can I access the value of a `SerializerMethodField` in `create()`?

Comment: You are sure if password key is on validate_date?, check out well if is key exist

Comment: @juliansalas Apparently it's not and thus the error. The question is how else do I access this(password)  field's value then?

Comment: Did you try `self.get_password()`? `SerializerMethodField` is a read-only field.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov TypeError: get_password() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
This is the error I am getting when I use self.get_password()

Answer (score 0):

`SerializerMethodField` ([Doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)) is a read-only field. This field is used when you want to compute the field for a given object and thus would not be necessary if you are receiving the input (write case). So, in you case you can generate password inside the create method and have only `name` in the serializer.

Comment: But in my case, I want to return this field after a successful request.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `get_password()` method by calling `self.get_password()` as @Andrey Shipilov mentioned. But remove the unnecessary second argument `obj` from definition of `get_password()`.

If what you require is to save a random password to database and return it in response, consider doing something like:

```
def create_password():
    from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
    password = get_random_string(length=16)
    return password

class ASCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(write_only = True)
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        name = validated_data['name']
        as = AS.objects.get_or_create(
                name = name,
                password = create_password()
            )
```

Comment: I am getting this error: AttributeError at /device/as/
'ASCreateSerializer' object has no attribute 'password' if I try to access self.password