# DRF Serializer access value of SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class SimpleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    value_x = serializers.SerializerMethodField('func_x')
    value_y = serializers.SerializerMethodField('func_y')

    def func_x(self, obj):
        return 0 

    def func_y(self, obj):
        value_x ??
```

In above's example is there any way to access the **variable** `value_x` within `func_y` whereas `value_x` should have the value of 0?

I've tried accessing it by just `value_x` and `self.value_x` but obviously both don't work

Comment: Call the other method? `value_x = self.func_x(obj)`

Comment: That would be inefficient since that method is already invoked when setting value_x @IainShelvington

Comment: What is the other method actually returning?

Comment: Doesn't matter @IainShelvington. I just want to use value_x for calculations in func_y. Whatever it returns is irrelevant for the question

Comment: Okay? Well you can't be sure which method will be called first so whatever func_x returns will need to be cached and called from func_y somehow

Comment: @IainShelvington That's the question....

Comment: The value being returned and how it's retrieved determines the appropriate way and place to cache it. If you just want a way to cache a value on a class use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property

Answer (score 1):

There's a hint in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623969/accessing-a-serializermethodfield-in-create) and its associated answers.

In your serializer you can access the other fields by using `self.get_<field_name>` as described in the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), i.e. in your case (you're overriding the method names so be aware of that) it should work like this:

```
class SimpleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    value_x = serializers.SerializerMethodField('func_x')
    value_y = serializers.SerializerMethodField('func_y')

    def func_x(self, obj):
        return 0 

    def func_y(self, obj):
        return self.func_x(obj) + 1
```

Side note: I like to move the `SerializerMethodField` function to a mixin to make it reusable and enhance maintainability, so I prefer something like the below.

```
class ValueXMixin():
    def get_value_x(self, obj):
        return self.func_x(obj) + 1


class ValueYMixin():
    def get_value_y(self, obj):
        return 0

class SimpleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer, ValueXMixin, ValueYMixin):
    value_x = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    value_y = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```